# Is it best-practise to commit the `BUILD.bazel` files generated by Gazelle?

Tags: go, bazel

I have a Go project that uses [`rules_go`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go) ([Bazel](https://www.bazel.build/)) to build the project. I'm using [Gazelle](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/tools/gazelle/README.rst) to generate `BUILD.bazel` files. Is it considered best-practise to commit the generated `BUILD.bazel` files into version control? Or is it best-practise to always do `bazel run //:gazelle` on new checkout and when new files have been added?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's generally best practice to commit build files for several reasons.

- Build files frequently contain rules, comments, and annotations which are not generated. For example, you might need to write a `genrule` to replace `go generate`. Or you might write a test that checks the copyright headers in your source files are up to date. Or you may want to tweak the visibility rules for some of your libraries.
- If any repository depends on your repository as a remote, it's convenient to have build files already checked in.
- In general, it's nice not to have to re-run Gazelle and similar tools before a build.